# SVG text hit-test

Tags: javascript, html, svg, collision-detection, hittest

I'm trying to implement collision detection for SVG text elements using client side JavaScript. The hit-test should check if any glyph of a text overlaps any glyph of another text element. Since `getBBox` and `getExtentOfChar` are anything than accurate I need a custom solution.

My first approach was to get the colour of each coordinate/pixel of an element and do the hit-testing manually, but this does not work because it isn't possible to get the colour of a coordinate. It would require an additional canvas to get pixel colours -> awful workaround.

Now I'm thinking about converting the text or the glyphs to polygons for hit testing. Is it possible? Or has anyone another approach for glyph based hit testing?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the pixel-based hit-testing – if you switch to HTML5 Canvas, then this will become possible. Several projects provide easy transition from SVG to Canvas, e.g. [fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js). [See a comparison table here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE&output=html).

As for the polygon-based approach – possible, but difficult. You can convert text or glyphs to polygons (paths) using some tool (Inkscape's text-to-path for instance). And then there'll be calculations. Making a general solution for any text will require a lot of work. However, if the text doesn't change, then drawing your text manually using paths can be a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are really entering a world of pain and cross browser problems. I ended up doing custom path-rendering of fonts only to get the *total* text length reliable and consistent. I don't even want to think about glyph-hitting.

One problem for example is that firefox (at least 3.6) and iirc also some version of opera has some rounding error when scaling so when you scale the parent-element holding the text and scale the text by the inverse of that scale, then the letter-spacing will be slightly different compared to without any scale. (Because each letter must begin on an even number or something like that, problem can be solved by multiplying both the upscale and downscale with like 10000 but that's another story)

The performance impact by using path compared to text is unfortunately quite noticeable. If your canvas does any form of animated panning or zooming you should switch to pure text-elements during the animation and once static, turn on path rendering for accuracy.

Fortunally converting svg-fonts to paths is very easy, it is plaintext and using the exact same format as the path-element. (beware of font-embedding-licenses though! Also keep file size in mind as you cannot use the fonts from the users system, )